# Add text just before the closing tag using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm using a Nokogiri-based helper to truncate text without breaking HTML tags:

```
require "rubygems"
require "nokogiri"

module TextHelper

  def truncate_html(text, max_length, ellipsis = "...")
    ellipsis_length = ellipsis.length
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse text
    content_length = doc.inner_text.length
    actual_length = max_length - ellipsis_length
    content_length > actual_length ? doc.truncate(actual_length).inner_html + ellipsis : text.to_s
  end

end

module NokogiriTruncator
  module NodeWithChildren
    def truncate(max_length)
      return self if inner_text.length <= max_length
      truncated_node = self.dup
      truncated_node.children.remove

      self.children.each do |node|
        remaining_length = max_length - truncated_node.inner_text.length
        break if remaining_length <= 0
        truncated_node.add_child node.truncate(remaining_length)
      end
      truncated_node
    end
  end

  module TextNode
    def truncate(max_length)
      Nokogiri::XML::Text.new(content[0..(max_length - 1)], parent)
    end
  end

end

Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.send(:include, NokogiriTruncator::NodeWithChildren)
Nokogiri::XML::Element.send(:include, NokogiriTruncator::NodeWithChildren)
Nokogiri::XML::Text.send(:include, NokogiriTruncator::TextNode)
```

On

```
content_length > actual_length ? doc.truncate(actual_length).inner_html + ellipsis : text.to_s
```

it appends the ellipse just after the last tag.

On my view I call

```
<%= truncate_html(news.parsed_body, 700, "... Read more.").html_safe %>
```

The issue is that the text that is being parsed is wrapped in `<p></p>` tags, causing the view to break:

```
"Lorem Ipsum</p>
... Read More"
```

Is it possible to append the ellipse to the last part of the last node using Nokogiri, so the final output becomes:

```
"Loren Ipsum... Read More</p>
```

Comment: Don't put `truncate_html` in your view. Preprocess the data in your controller, assign it to a variable and access just that variable in your view.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't supply any input data you get to interpolate from this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
<p>foo bar baz</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT

paragraph = doc.at('p')
text = paragraph.text
text[4..-1] = '...'
paragraph.content = text
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <body>
# >> <p>foo ...</p>
# >> </body>
# >> </html>
```

You're making it much harder than it really is. Nokogiri is smart enough to know whether we're passing markup, or simply text, and `content` will create a text node or an element depending on which it is.

This code simply:

1. Finds the `p` tag.
2. Extracts the text from it.
3. Replaces the text from a given point to the end with `'...'`.
4. Replaces the content of the paragraph with that text.

If you only want to append to that text it becomes even easier:

```
paragraph = doc.at('p')
paragraph.content = paragraph.text + ' ...Read more.'
puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >> <body>
# >> <p>foo bar baz ...Read more.</p>
# >> </body>
# >> </html>
```